# Add user_id in photo uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using RoR 2.3.8.

I let users to upload photos using paperclip, but there is no ownership in the photo. Which means, I don't know who uploaded the photos at all.

Here, I would like to have a new column in Photos model, `user_id` and everytime a user uploads a picture, his ID will be automatically included in the column.

How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: if they are logged in, you should have a current_user helper you can use directly.

Comment: I know I should first add a column in Photo, called user_id, then add `belongs_to :user` in Photo.rb, what's next?

Comment: In User.rb you should add `has_many :photos` then in your controller you can use the code in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are <strike>two</strike> three ways of doing this.

Either add the new photo to the user's photo collection:

```
current_user.photos << Photo.new(params[:photo])
```

Or like this:

```
current_user.photos.build(params[:photo])
```

Or assign the logged in (current) user to the new photo:

```
photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
photo.user = current_user
```

Comment: I think this should work. Will try in a while. Another quick question: when I create a new model with user_id in the migration, I still need to do this in the new controller right?

Comment: Yeah, you still need this, because the photo (or whatever model) doesn't magically to which user it belongs. You have to assign it.

Comment: What apneadiving is suggesting is also possible, but that doesn't feel right to me. I would not expect this 'functionality' to be in the view...

Comment: I ended up using this: @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo].merge(:user =>current_user)). Thanks!

Comment: So you ended up taking apneadiving's advice. Thanks for accepting my answer ;-)

Comment: On the merge param part. Sometimes there are several good answers that work, and I feel bad to only able to accept just one answer. Could you vote up apneadiving's answer too?

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In your migration file, set a column with an integral value called "user_id" in the photo model

Then you can call

```
@user.photos
```

or

```
@photo.user
```

Comment: it should be `belongs_to :user`, not 'has_one'

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

1. add `user_id` in photos table
2. add `belongs_to :user`in Photo model
3. add `has_many :photos` in your User model
4. add a hidden field in you photo form `f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user`
5. beware to set `user_id` as `attr_accessible`

If ever you fear user hack the html and add photos for other, you should merge params in your controller instead of adding a field in the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Devise gem - just add this to your photo_controller:

```
def create
  @photo.user = current_user
  ...
end
```